# Summing with a column but potentially use another column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have this table

campaignArchive

```
id   campaignID   bannerID   poolID   limitImpressions      actualImpressions
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
1    496          10367      7        12500                 205
2    497          10367      7        12500                 22860
3    498          10367      7        12500                 1525
```

I need to sum actual impressions to date, which would ordinarily just be:

```
select sum(actualImpressions) as actuals from campaignArchive
```

However, if the actualImpressions column value exceeds the limitImpressions column value (as in row 2), I want the limitImpressions column value to be used instead.

Hope that makes sense. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to include a `case` statement.

```
select
    sum(case when actualImpressions > limitImpressions 
             then limitImpressions 
             else actualImpressions end) as actuals

from campaignArchive
```